# Enable UISearchDisplayController to search text contains string

Tags: sql, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

This is my `UISearchDisplayController` that works if I perform search and return the result with matching starting alphabet. 
However, what I what to do is to enable searching of text contains string. 
For example, if I have data `chocolate chip` and `dark chocolate`, when I type `chocolate` on the search bar, I wish to return both result. 
The following code only return `chocolate chip` but not `dark chocolate` :

```
self.searchDisplayController = [[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self] autorelease];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Matches", @"");

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSString *text = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([text length]) {
        [self.db fetchCompletionListWithString:text callback:^(NSArray *list) {
            self.prefixArray = list;
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }];
    }
}
```

This is the `fetchCompletionListWithString`

```
- (void)_fetchCompletionListWithString:(NSString *)inStr callback:(void(^)(NSArray *))inCallback
{
    if (!inStr || ![inStr length]) {
        return;
    }

    const char *SQL = "SELECT id,title FROM entries WHERE title LIKE ? || '%';";
    ObjSqliteStatement *statement = [[ObjSqliteStatement alloc] initWithSQL:SQL db:db];
    [statement bindText:inStr toColumn:1];
    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
    while ([statement step]) {
        NSInteger entryID = [statement intFromColumn:0];
        NSString *title = [statement textFromColumn:1];
        if (entryID) {
            [list addObject:@{kMDIdentifierKey:@(entryID), kMDTitleKey:title}];
        }
    }
    [statement release];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        inCallback(list);
    });
}
```

I tried to change the `*SQL` to `"SELECT id,title FROM entries WHERE title LIKE ? '%' || '%';"`. But this do not work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on where you query the result.

If you query on an Array, use NSPredicate to filter the result like this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchToken];
```

If you query on Database, use SQL query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '%chocolate%'
```

Hope this help.

Base on your edit, you can try this way as a tricky (Because your library you use is so old). If you want to handle SQL, i recommend you use [Realm](http://realm.io/)

```
- (void)_fetchCompletionListWithString:(NSString *)inStr callback:(void(^)(NSArray *))inCallback
{
    if (!inStr || ![inStr length]) {
        return;
    }
inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",inStr];
    const char *SQL = "SELECT id,title FROM entries WHERE title LIKE ? ;";
    ObjSqliteStatement *statement = [[ObjSqliteStatement alloc] initWithSQL:SQL db:db];
    [statement bindText:inStr toColumn:1];
    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
    while ([statement step]) {
        NSInteger entryID = [statement intFromColumn:0];
        NSString *title = [statement textFromColumn:1];
        if (entryID) {
            [list addObject:@{kMDIdentifierKey:@(entryID), kMDTitleKey:title}];
        }
    }
    [statement release];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        inCallback(list);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `use of undeclared identifier 'str'` and `unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression` errors.